# OAuth2.0 in iOS?

Tags: ios, callback, oauth-2.0, afnetworking-2, fitbit

I am trying to use FitBit api in iOS application. I have a fitbit device and I am trying to create an iOS app that connects with the FitBit api and gets my data back. I am trying to implement OAuth2.0. I already have the client ID but I have been stuck. I am not sure how to proceed with this. I have read the documentation on how OAuth works and how fibit works with OAuth2.0 . My problem is I don't know how to open the fibit api authenication by the user, and how to get the access token. How do I proceed after getting the access token. 
I am a noob to this, so I would appreciate if somebody can guide me how to go with that. If someone can guide me to similar projects it will be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing OAuth isn't a simple task. I started with [Christian Hansen's OAuth Example](https://github.com/chrhansen/simple-oauth2) and modified it to work for my project (his is for Google, but it can be changed to work with FitBit or anything else).

You can also check out one of the many [OAuth Client wrappers on GitHub](https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client). Those two should get you close enough that you can start asking more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks InkGolem. I have successfully acquired the access_token. Now I just have to pass it in the header to get the required data. Thanks for the resources. I will gladly check them out.

Comment: @Rosh no problem! Would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Here is a sample for FitBit+Oauth2
https://github.com/Stasonis/fitbit-api-example-swift